# Is it ok to flog people for circumventing the minimum answer size?

Tags: discussion, fun

I hate coming across answers like "Yes. (need at least 30 characters in answer)"

Don't people realize there's a **reason** there's a minimum?  Maybe to give someone a more useful answer?

Comment: Thanks, it's always nice to learn of new English words. "1 beat (someone) with a whip or stick as punishment or torture: *the stolen horses will be returned and the thieves flogged* | (flogging) *public floggings*" :) [I assumed you meant "flag"; maybe I'm wrong, but I'm grateful nonetheless.]

Comment: No, I really meant flog, heh

Comment: You have a +1 for obvious reasons for every answer except the one for which the reason is most obvious. I'm almost confused, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Because I gave a +1 for a much *better* reason, "an actual, legitimate answer."  :)

Comment: As in sell into slavery?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you hate those answers ... PLEASE

#### Downvote them

People do not vote enough on our sites. You could also flag them if they are obvious cases of abuse.

Comment: </couldn't-resist>

Comment: +1 for an actual, legitimate answer, heh

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Hah, did you just downvote his answer?

Comment: Yeah, and then everybody had to ruin the gag by voting it back up. Comedy is hard.

Comment: @MusiGenesis ... now who is laughing ... :)

Comment: Correction: People do not *downvote* enough.  There's plenty of indiscriminate upvoting.

Comment: I don't downvote as much as I'd otherwise, because in my experience, downvotes tend to attract pity upvotes, unless the Q or A is *really* bad. So it feels counterproductive.

Answer (score 15):

No.

Comment: _</couldn't-resist>_

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

Comment: So you think people should be punished?

Comment: @waiwai933: By "flog" I assume the OP means downvote or leave a salty comment, so yes.  But now you've tricked me into leaving a more useful answer.  ಠ_ಠ

Comment: +1 also for obvious reasons

Comment: which ​​are...?

Comment: succinct. :)...